# Display organized data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm working on a Winforms project that handle a SQL Server database, I use Linq to entities for the interactions. After setting up a form for adding new Items to the relational database Tables(***articles***, *categories*, *sources*), I need to show and organize the content of ***articles***  in another form, class them by category, filter only the articles of a specified *source* or that contains a specified keyword, select an article and update/delete it..., then I need to generate a report listing only the articles of such *category*, with the name and the source of each one; I don't know from where begin to achieve that! This is my first month with c#, I've learned the basics, searched on the Internet, but I still don't find how to do this correctly. Is `DataGridView` and some buttons sufficient enough to do the organisation part? Is there other best solution or suitable technology? For the reporting, will Crystal Report satisfy me or should I start searching an alternative? Give me some advices or some good tutorials please!

Comment: I suggest you get a book.

Comment: @Nick Why not! Do you know a good one?

Comment: Not specifically but make sure it covers Winforms and ADO.net.

Comment: Everything went fine with just dataGridView and InnerJoin.